# Session expiration in Extjs ajax calls

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, extjs, load

Session expires frequently in extjs load() function. When i'm trying to load data into forms, grids and tabpanels frequently session is expiring.

Example form load

```
exam_edit_form.load({
    url: 'page_url.php',
    method:'POST',
    success: function(form, action){
        var chapter_name = action.result.data.test_chapter_combo;
        Ext.getCmp('chap_exam_id').setValue(chapter_name);
    } 
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a session update happening during an AJAX call. The session ID is not retained by the browser, and the session is lost and regenerated on the next call.

The CodeIgniter community is aware of the issue and is currently working out the resolution. https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/154

The bug report has some potential fixes.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe ExtJs will specify the Problem in property failureType?

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.action.Action-property-failureType